# nodejs openshift cartridge - not reading custom environment variables

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am identifying my openshift nodejs app environment through system environment variables Ex: 'staging', 'production'. My custom environment variable name is `OPENSHIFT_APP_ENV`. I have set this in `.bash_profile` and ran `source .bash_profile`.

When I did `printenv` or `echo $OPENSHIFT_APP_ENV` in command line in my openshift app, I can see the values set properly.

But these variables are not read/set in my nodejs app. I am simply trying to read it as `global.ENV = process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_ENV || "development";`

I feel that it should be simple setting issue, but could not get this working somehow. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `rhc env set` command as explained in this section (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#custom-variables) of the Developer Center to set your environment variables.  Especially if you are using a scaled application, that makes sure that your custom environment variables are created on all gears.

It is also standard practice (i believe) to use the NODE_ENV environment variable to determine what environment you are operating in.

You should also make sure to stop & start (not restart) your application after you create environment variables to make sure that your process picks them up correctly (may solve your issue of your application not seeing the ones from your .bash_profile, but i would still recommend using the rhc env set command instead)